# Maximize the sizes of thumbnails in a grid

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, optimization

I have an application where I display thumbnails of several images loaded from a local folder.

There are few constraints:

- all the images have the same size - but I will know it only at run-time
- the window must show all the images on a single page, arranging them in a grid layout

I'm looking for a way to calculate the best size for the thumbnails in order to maximize their dimensions on the screen.

In summary we know:

- width and height in pixel of each image (they are all the same)
- width and height in pixel of the available space
- the desired gap in pixel among them (the same for rows and columns)
- the numbers of the images to be displayed
- the margins in pixel (left, right, top, bottom)

I want to calculate:

- width and height in pixel of the thumbnails
- columns and rows of the resulting grid

This how I would proceed, but I'm open to better hints!

1. calculate the image size ratio: width / height
2. find two numbers that their products is greater (or equal) to the number of the images, and their ratio is close to the ratio just calculated. They will be the rows and columns of the grid
3. now calculate the actual available size of the working area as: space available - margins - gap * cols-1 (or rows-1)
4. divide this for the cols (or rows) to have the size of the thumbnail

Do you agree?
What's the easiest approach for point 2?

The underlying idea is of course that if the images are like squares, the best is a grid with cols = rows. Instead, if the images have a long width, but they are very thin, it's better to have a grid with few cols and more rows...

It's not a question directly related to any language programming, anyway I'm writing my application in C#.

Comment: Other idea: divide window area by image number to get an upper bound for the image area. Compute image size from image area. Reduce image width so that it divides nicely into the window width. Reduce image height proportionally.

Comment: Interesting approach. I'm going to give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get really available space

```
W = availWidth - 2 * margin
H = availHeight - 2 * margin
Cf = imHeight / imWidth
```

and find the largest solution of the next inequality  (for example, with binary search) to fill available space.

```
(W div (x + gap)) * (H div (Cf * x + gap)) >= NumImages
//(div is integer division)
```

If the last row contains too few images, check a pair of neighbour x (thumb width) values to get "smarter" grid filling

Comment: Ok, so I have to "search" the best fit value. This was my doubt.